# Crypto.createDecipheriv - Error: Unsupported state or unable to authenticate data @ decipher.final()

Tags: node.js, cryptojs

I'm getting this error message:
`Error: Unsupported state or unable to authenticate data`
when trying to decrypt information in my frontend sent by my backend.

This is my backend code:

```
const userInfo = await this.permsRepository.find({
            where: {
                email: email,
            },
        });
        
        // Generate initialization vector
        const iv = randomBytes(16);
        // Get secret key
        const key = process.env.USERSECRET;
        // Encryption settings
        const cipher = createCipheriv('aes-256-gcm', Buffer.from(key), iv);

        // Encrypt
        const stringUserInfo = JSON.stringify(userInfo);
        let encryptedUserInfo = cipher.update(stringUserInfo, 'utf-8', 'hex');
        encryptedUserInfo += cipher.final('hex');

        const tag = cipher.getAuthTag().toString('hex');

        return {
            iv: iv.toString('hex'), 
            data: encryptedUserInfo,
            tag: tag
        }
```

And this is how I'm trying to decrypt it in the frontend:

```
const iv = Buffer.from(`${encryptJson.iv}`, 'hex');
        const encryptedInfo = Buffer.from(`${encryptJson.data}`, 'hex');
        // Get secret key
        const key = process.env.USERSECRET;
        // Configure decipher
        const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-gcm', Buffer.from(key), Buffer.from(iv));
        decipher.setAuthTag(Buffer.from(`${encryptJson.tag}`, 'hex'));

        try {
            let decrypted = decipher.update(encryptedInfo, 'hex', 'utf-8');
            decrypted += decipher.final('utf-8');

            console.log(decrypted.toString());
```

I've been searching for similar questions, but it seems like all of their problems are fixed by adding the authTags to their cipher and decipher, something I already have in both of my encrypt and decrypt functions.

I'm still getting that error, specifically at the line where the `decipher.final()` is being appended to the `decrypted` object.

Comment: Not reproducible: https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/GYW. Check key and other data.

Comment: I've copied over my frontend code to my backend and it was working as well.
I tried setting a hardcoded key like your example, but it's still returning the same error.
I am starting to think it might have something to do with how data is being processed in server vs. client.
Could the fact that I'm using the `crypto` package in the backend, but `const crypto = require('crypto-browserify');` in the frontend be part of the problem? Since I'm using Webpack 5.0, `crypto` is no longer auto-included.

Comment: Environment specific problems are hard to analyze. Compare the data on the encryption side with the data on the decryption side (ciphertext, IV, tag, key), then you should find which data is corrupted and may be able to conclude the cause.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to solve the issue using the `crypto` library directly, so I began researching possible alternatives.

I ended up using `crypto-js`'s AES on both my front- and back-end.
Encrypting and decrypting using its included methods solved the problem I was having.

I am unsure of what could have been causing the environment discrepancies.